# Count ways to assign weights for a Tree so that w1 <= w2 <= ... <= wm

Tags: algorithm, tree

**Question:**

Given a tree with **N nodes** and an array of **M pairs of nodes** from that tree, the pairs are indexed from 1->m.

Have ***w[i]*** as the sum of weights on the path between the pair of nodes after modulo by 2. So ***w[i]*** can either be 0 or 1.

**Count ways to assign weights for the Tree so that *w1* <= *w2* <= ... <= *wm***

*The weights can only be 1 or 2.*

**Constraints:**

```
N, M <= 30000
```

**Example:**

The graph:

[image: example graph]

The M pairs of nodes:

```
1 2
2 3
1 3
```

Answer: 2

**Explaination:**

Here are all the possible ways to assign edges:

***Way 1:***

```
Edge: 1 - 2 weight: 1
Edge: 1 - 3 weight: 1 

w[] would be {1, 1, 0}
-> Not valid
```

***Way 2:***

```
Edge: 1 - 2 weight: 1
Edge: 1 - 3 weight: 2 

w[] would be {1, 0, 1}
-> Not valid
```

***Way 3:***

```
Edge: 1 - 2 weight: 2
Edge: 1 - 3 weight: 1 

w[] would be {0, 1, 1}
-> Valid
```

***Way 4:***

```
Edge: 1 - 2 weight: 2
Edge: 1 - 3 weight: 2 

w[] would be {0, 0, 0}
-> Valid
```

*Other valid `w[]` such as `{0, 0, 1}` or `{1, 1, 1}` is not counted as an answer because there are no way to assign weights to get the above arrays.*

**My take on O(2^N * M):**

My best solution so far is to generate all possible weight assignments for the graph and check if it's valid. Which is clearly not the best way.

Is there any hint or keyword that can help me find out an optimized solution for this problem?

***P/S:** Sorry for my bad English, please comment if anything needs to be clarify*

Comment: I can come up with 4 different ways to assign weights within the parameters that you've given: `{0,0,0}, {0,0,1}, {0,1,1}, {1,1,1}`.  You've excluded 2 of these, but there's no rule given that should exclude them.

Comment: @RBarryYoung it is impossible to assign weights so that `w[] = {1, 1, 1}`. I think you misunderstood the question, the `w[]` array and the weights of the tree is different.

Comment: There is nothing in your post or your comment that explains why `{1,1,1}` is not an acceptable answer.  You need to explain this additional rule before we can answer your question.

Comment: @RBarryYoung i have given a better explaination

Comment: "Have w[i] as the sum of weights on the path between the pair of nodes after modulo by 2. So w[i] can either be 1 or 2." -- I think you mean that w[i] can be 0 or 1, since 2 mod 2 is zero.

Comment: @Dave my bad, I have fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant body of knowledge is linear algebra over the finite field
with two elements (GF(2)), and graph homology specifically.

- Given edge weights, the function from a vector representing a set of
  edges to the total weight of those edges in GF(2) is a linear map.
- The XOR (that is, sum in GF(2)) of the tree path from A to B and the
  tree path from B to C is the tree path from A to C.

Let G be the graph whose edges are the m given pairs. For each valid
**w** vector, we can use depth-first search in G to count the number of
valid solutions. Correctness follows from the rank–nullity theorem.

In each connected component C of G, which the depth-first search roots
at some node r, we record for each node x in C the parity of the sum of
edge weights from r to x. Whenever we find a tree arc, we can compute
the parity of the head from the parity of the tail. Whenever we find a
back arc, we can do the same, but the head already has a parity. If the
parities disagree, then there are no solutions for this particular
**w**.

Each tree arc corresponds to an independent equation, so by
rank–nullity, if there is any solution, then there are 2<sup>n−1−k</sup>
of them, where k is the number of tree arcs.

Comment: For each valid w[]  we have to do a DFS, won't that make the complexity O(2^N * N)? Since there're around 2^N valid w[]

Comment: @unglinh279 no, we're enumerating the m + 1 valid outputs, not the 2^(n-1) valid inputs.

Comment: I don't quite understand the part where we check if a particular `w[]` is valid or not. Can you make it a bit more clearly?